# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created a multi module maven project. I placed all the spring configuration file in spring-conf module. and while deployed the application in jboss eap but while running the server it is throwing **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource** error.

Below is my web xml and applicationContext.xml.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml,
                 classpath:/META-INF/spring/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
       <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/spring-mvc-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.dao" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:property-placeholder location="file:/var/company/properties/mail.properties" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

    <import resource="classpath:/spring/spring-company-core.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/spring/spring-company-dao.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/spring/spring-company-mail.xml" />

    <bean id="db_DataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/OracleDS" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>     
</beans>
```

I am getting below exception:

**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/spring-company-mail.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/spring-company-mail.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist**

if I copy the content of spring-company-mail.xml and comment the import spring-company-mail.xml in applicationContext.xml file then its working fine

Could you help me where I am wrong?

**root pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>company</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>companyParent</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

**parent pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>company</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>companyParent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>company-core</module>
    <module>company-web</module>
    <module>company-war</module>
    <module>company-script</module>
    <module>company-conf</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
        <!-- Spring version -->
        <version.spring>4.0.1.RELEASE</version.spring>
        <vsersion.spring.security>3.2.0.RELEASE</vsersion.spring.security>
        <hibernate-version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate-version>
        <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>

        <!-- Spring Third Party dependencies -->
        <version.aopalliance>1.0</version.aopalliance>

        <!-- Third Party dependencies -->
        <version.standard.taglibs>1.1.2</version.standard.taglibs>
        <version.commons.logging>1.1.1</version.commons.logging>

        <!-- JBoss AS plugin for deployment -->
        <version.jboss.as.maven.plugin>7.1.1.Final</version.jboss.as.maven.plugin>

    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- Define the versions of JBoss EAP components we want to use -->
            <!-- Define the version of JBoss' Java EE 6 APIs we want to import. Any 
                dependencies from org.jboss.spec will have their version defined by this 
                BOM -->
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill 
                of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
                of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
                of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-web-6.0 stack (you can read this 
                as the JBoss stack of the Java EE Web Profile 6 APIs), and we use version 
                3.0.0.Final-redhat-1 which is the latest release of the stack. You can actually 
                use this stack with any version of JBoss AS that implements Java EE 6, not 
                just JBoss AS 7! -->
            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId> <artifactId>jboss-javaee-web-6.0</artifactId> 
                <version>3.0.0.Final-redhat-1</version> <type>pom</type> <scope>import</scope> 
                </dependency> -->

            <!-- Spring dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
                <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Security -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${vsersion.spring.security}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${vsersion.spring.security}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${vsersion.spring.security}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- hibernate -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Third Party dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
                <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
                <version>${version.aopalliance}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                <version>${version.standard.taglibs}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>${version.commons.logging}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Apache Tiles -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>       
                <version>${velocity.version}</version>    
            </dependency>   
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Import the JPA API using the provided scope It is included in JBoss 
            AS 7 / EAP 6 -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId> 
            <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
            annotations are incorrectly used. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import Spring dependencies, these are either from community or versions 
            certified in WFK2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other community dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>              
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>           
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!-- Java Mail API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- Add cglib for the MemberDaoTest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add H2 dependency for embedded testing database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.165</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add JSON dependency, specified in jboss-deployment-structure.xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jasper dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
         <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
            <version>4.16.4.Final</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--  Added Log4j dependency -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>                      
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>           
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**war pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>companyParent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>company-conf</artifactId>
</project>

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>com.abc.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>companyParent</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>
        <artifactId>companyFinance-war</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>companyFinance-war Maven Webapp</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.abc.company</groupId>
                <artifactId>company-core</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.abc.company</groupId>
                <artifactId>company-web</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.abc.company</groupId>
                <artifactId>company-conf</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <finalName>company-war</finalName>

        </build>
    </project>
```

**conf pom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>companyParent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>company-conf</artifactId>
</project>
```

Comment: Would you share you poms

Comment: @Essex Boy added pom.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 projects one is config with all the xml files in the src/main/resources directory.  The main project will then have a dependency to the config project.  Here is my test pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>net.isban</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>example-jar</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>example-jar</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.isban</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-config</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So now the example project has access to anything in the example-config project on its classpath.  The test below shows this (test.properties is in the example-config:/src/main/resources directory):

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    String string = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.properties"));
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

So in your case you would just need to do a

```
<import resource="classpath:spring-company-core.xml" />
```

Assuming you spring-company-core.xml is in the src/main/resources of your config project.

Comment: I added the config dependency in war module. But my point is if I comment mail xml file in applicationContext.xml then how come it is working?

Comment: <import resource="classpath:spring-company-core.xml" /> will work if the xml file is in the classpath, this includes anything in the config projects /src/main/resources directory.

Comment: I have all the config xml files in company-conf module src/main/resources/spring/ and I included the .xml files in application context core and dao xml are importing and there is no issue but, when I import mail xml file its throwing filenotfound exception.

Comment: I got my mistake. There is typo mistake instead of company-mail.xml I typed Company-mail.xml

Comment: Do you have another version of the conf project in your local repo (~/.m2/repo) to make sure you use the module under the same parent you should use <version>${project.version}</version>
 not <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>.

Comment: OK glad you found it, but I would still do what I suggest in the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you so much @Essex